# Xcode swift navigation bar disappears when simulator runs, but not whilst in storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller

My app has two main views which are switched on orientation change, the view whilst in portrait mode should have a navigation bar across it (my code is tested in a separate application which works perfectly so I've either transferred it wrong, pressed some strange option that disables the bar on runtime, or the system is incompatible with the landscape view controller, which is not linked to the navigation controller) but it doesn't.

P.S: The label changes it's value to the string on the table cell that is pressed, and the animal/mounth

Storyboard showing navigation bars:
[image: Storyboard showing navigation bars]

Screenshot showing simulator without navigation bar on the table view in the broken project:
[image: Screenshot showing simulator without navigation bar on the table view in the broken project]

----Wanted to post these links but didn't have enough reputation points----

Screenshot of result from tapping a table cell, should have a back arrow in top left

Screenshot from the working testProject (which doesn't contain the view which is instantiated when the device is orientated to landscape) which shows what the previous screen shot should look like

I'm also going to show my app delegate class which contains the main difference between the working project and the broken project:

```
var window: UIWindow?
var storyboard:UIStoryboard!
var initialViewController:UIViewController!

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Create rotation function and call it whenever the device is rotated
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.rotated), name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

    // Set default ViewController based on rotation
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    // Declare InitialViewController as portrait to avoid NSInternalInconsistencyException
    initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PortraitViewController")

    // Declare initial view controller based on device orientation
    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation)){
        initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PortraitViewController")
    } else if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation)){
        initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LandscapeViewController")
    }

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}

/// Called when the screen is rotated
func rotated()
{
    // if device is landscape show LandscapeViewController
    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
    {
        initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LandscapeViewController")
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    // if device is portrait show PortraitViewController
    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
    {
        initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PortraitViewController")
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn it, fixed this immediately. I'll post my fix to help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I was instantiating the portrait view controller when the app loaded in portrait position which was loading the view directly instead of loading it through the navigation controller, therefore stopping the navbar from ever being loaded. So i went to my storyboard and gave the navigation controller the storyboard id "NavController", then I replaced all uses of "PortraitViewController" in AppDelegate with "NavController" this meant that the nav controller was loading the table view instead of the application skipping and loading the table view without a navbar on launch.